# Well-foundedness: classical equivalence of no infinite descent and accessibility

Tags: coq, classical-logic, axiom-of-choice

I have often seen the claim that in a classical setting, well-foundedness of a relation `>` defined as the absence of an infinite descent `x_0 > x_1 > x_2 > ...` is equivalent to the constructive definition using an accessibility predicate as in Coq's `Acc`:

```
Inductive Acc (x: A) : Prop :=
  Acc_intro : (forall y:A, R y x -> Acc y) -> Acc x.

Definition well_founded := forall a:A, Acc a.
```

where `R : A -> A -> Prop`.

It seems it requires some version of choice but I don't know which is weakest one has to assume to construct such a proof.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not a Coq proof, but it's a proof sketch using the [axiom of dependent choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice) and LEM to exhibit an equivalence. I believe this is the weakest choice principle you can get away with, but I cannot find a reference. It's too long for a comment unfortunately.

Edit: it's no longer just a paper proof! @kyo dralliam has formalized [the below argument in Coq](https://gist.github.com/kyoDralliam/73b270f18d6c2a0b5725fc73afc21d61) and gone further to show that the choice additional axioms (dependent choice, LEM) are also necessary as well as sufficient.

---

Let's define $\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a)$ to be the proposition which states that there is an infinite descending chain in $(A,R)$ starting with $a$:
$$
\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a) = \exists f : \mathbb{N} \to A.\ f(0) = a \land (\forall n.\ f(n) \mathrel{R} f(n + 1))
$$

We will show that $\neg \mathsf{idc}(A,R,a) \iff \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,a)$. The $\Leftarrow$ direction follows by induction on $\mathsf{Acc}$ and requires no non-constructive principles. The inductive step can be summarized as "if $\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a)$ holds, there is some $b$ such that $a \mathrel{R} b$ and $\mathsf{idc}(A,R,b)$ holds."

For the other direction, let's use LEM and assume $\neg \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,a)$ to derive a contradiction. We will achieve this contradiction by constructing an infinite descending chain and this is where we will use the axiom of dependent choice.

To that end, consider the type $B(a) = \{x : A \mid a \mathrel{R^*} x \land \neg \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,x)\}$ and write $S$ for the restriction of $R$ to this type. Let's prove that $S$ is entire, that is if $b : B(a)$ then there exists some $c$ such that $b \mathrel{S} c$. I've deferred this lemma to the bottom of the answer, to not clutter up the proof. Since $(B(a),S)$ is entire and non-empty with $a : B$ by assumption, the axiom of dependent choice gives us an infinite descending chain within $B(a)$: $b_0 \mathrel{S} b_1 \mathrel{S} b_2 \mathrel{S} b_3 \dots$. By definition of $S$, this induces a chain $b_0 \mathrel{R} b_1 \mathrel{R} b_2 \dots$. Moreover, by definition of $B(a)$ we can extend this chain so that it starts with $a$. We now derive our contradiction from $\neg\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a)$.

---

**Lemma**. $(B(a),S)$ is entire.

*Proof*. Assume we are given $b : B(a)$. By assumption, $\neg \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,b)$. Unfolding this, we see that it's equivalent to the following:
$$
\neg (\forall b. a \mathrel{R} b \to \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,b))
$$

By LEM again, we obtain $c : A$ such that $a \mathrel{R} c$ and $\neg \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,c)$. Therefore, $c : B(a)$ and $b \mathrel{S} c$ as required.

---

Comment: This argument more precisely that $\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a) \iff \neg\mathsf{Acc}(A,R,a)$. LEM is necessary to prove this: Take $A=\{a\}$ then $\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a) \iff a \mathrel{R} a$ and $\mathsf{Acc}(A,R,a) \iff \lnot(a \mathrel{R} a)$. Since $R$ is arbitrary, LEM follows from the equivalence. The stated equivalence $\lnot\mathsf{idc}(A,R,a) \iff \mathsf{Acc}(A,R,a)$ appears to be a bit more subtle.

Comment: Dependent choice is also necessary, see [here](https://gist.github.com/kyoDralliam/73b270f18d6c2a0b5725fc73afc21d61) for a proof in Coq.

Comment: @kyodralliam: Very good, you beat me to it in formalization :-) The answer should be updated with a refefence to Kenji's proof.

Comment: @kyodralliam Very cool! I've added a paragraph to the above answer.

Answer (score 8):

The Lean proof is [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/order/order_iso_nat.html#rel_embedding.well_founded_iff_no_descending_seq). It uses the axiom of choice as stated [here](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib_docs/init/classical.html#classical.axiom_of_choice)

I can summarise as follows. We'll prove that if a relation is not well founded, then there is an infinite descending sequence (we used excluded middle here). For any `x` such that `¬ acc r x`, there exists a smaller `y` such that `¬ acc r y`. This is because the definition of `acc` is that everything smaller is `acc`. There's another use of excluded middle here.

We also use excluded middle to prove the existence of one `x` such that `¬ acc r x`

So we have `∀ x : {a // ¬ acc r a}, ∃ y : {a // ¬ acc r a}, y.1 < x.1`,
and from this, using the axiom of choice, we have the existence of a function `{a // ¬ acc r a} → {a // ¬ acc r a}` such that `r (f x) x`. We can iterate this function to define our infinite descending sequence.

Comment: I think “`y` such that `¬ acc r x`” should be “`y` such that `¬ acc r y`”, but edits must be 6 characters, so I can't make the change.

Comment: Thanks, I made the edit

Comment: If I could I would have accepted this answer too. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to point out, dependent choice is strictly weaker than full AC (addressing the "weakest" part of the question).

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question! My guess would be that just using LEM a relation is well-founded iff it does not contain an entire inverse subrelation. Turning this into a descending sequence represented as function from the natural numbers then sounds like dependend choice maybe?

I have checked the argument now [in Coq](https://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/%7Ekirst/downloads/Acc.v) and while the answers given in the meantime perfectly explain the equivalence to DC, here's a brief addition/refinement regarding the use of DC depending on the concrete formulation of infinite descent.

The usual definition Théo already suggested by the notation $x_0>x_1>x_2>\dots$ is based on a function $f:\mathbb N \to X$ representing a descending chain. However, descent can also be formulated as a non-empty set $P$ such that for all $x\in P$ there is $y\in P$ with $y< x$. This notion of an entire subrelation shows up in Daniel's answer and its absence is indeed equivalent to well-foundedness just using LEM:

- If $<$ is well-founded, then there is no entire subrelation $P$. Proof: As before by induction on Acc for the witness $x\in P$ of non-emptiness.
- Given LEM, if there is no entire subrelation, then $<$ is well-founded. Proof: Exactly as before, suppose $x$ were not accessible, then the inaccessible points form an entire subrelation.

This now localises the use of DC, since this is exactly the requirement to turn an entire subrelation into a chain, the other direction is of course for free:

- If there is no entire subrelation, then there is no descending chain. Proof: Assume $f$ were a descending chain, then its range induces an entire subrelation.
- Given DC, if there is no descending chain, then there is no entire subrelation. Proof: Assume $P$ were entire, then using DC on the type $\Sigma P$ and the relation $\lambda x y.\, y < x$ yields a descending chain.

(Of course the above implications are actually proven in the stronger contrapostive form but I chose the weaker form to align with well-foundedness.)